# Как обратиться к потомку в родительском методе?

Tags: python, наследование

В результате выполнения получаю 'A', а хочу получить имя того класса из которого обращаюсь к родительскому методу, то есть 'B'.

```
class A:
    def class_name():
        print(__class__.__name__)

class B(A):
    pass

B.class_name()
```

Как это сделать?

Можно конечно так:

```
class A:
    def class_name(cls):
        print(cls.__name__)

class B(A):
    pass

B.class_name(B)
```

но не хочется передавать параметр, масло маслянное.

Comment: Можно так https://stackoverflow.com/a/11408458/7485582.  Со статичным методом, я думаю, не выйдет. Ну или адекватным способом не выйдет.

Answer (score 3):

Можно вот так через декоратор метода класса:

```
class A:
    @classmethod
    def class_name(cls):
        print(cls.__name__)


class B(A):
    pass

A.class_name()  # A
B.class_name()  # B
```

Answer (score 1):

Можете попробовать такой вариант

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print(self.__class__.__name__)

class B(A):
    pass

B()
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, такое вам подойдëт

```
class A():
    def class_name(self):
        print(self.__class__.__name__)

class B(A):
    pass

B().class_name()
```